# Finding the right rules to filter certain strings in python list

Tags: python

I have a large plain text file and I have to 'clean' it in **python3**.

For now I've read it into a list with the following strings:

```
['[chr10:43612033[C', '[chr10:61665880[G', 'C[chr20:3835205[', ']chr20:3870375]T', 'G]chr6:117650611]']
```

My **goal** is to turn it into a list containing only the string of the middle part `'chr_XX:number'`. That means I need to find a way to either remove 1 or 2 characters from the beginning and the end of the origninal string.

```
['chr10:43612033', 'chr10:61665880', 'chr20:3835205', 'chr20:3870375', 'chr6:117650611']
```

My **problem** here is, that I can not slice by index as the pattern is:

<chr>+ any number between 1-22 or X or Y
E.g. `chr1` or `chr22` or `chrX` or `chrY`

The part after the `:` can be **any** integer number spanning up to 9 digits.
Thus, I cannot just slice by removing the the first x characters or the last x characters.

This is because sometimes I have 2 characters before my relevant string and sometimes only one.
As in:

```
<any_letter>]chr10:<the_number>
```

or

```
]chr10:<the_integer>
```

or the same story but with the opening square bracket `[` .

The same goes for the final part of the string. After my famous integer of any length between 1 and 9 digits i got either `]<any_letter>` or just a single `]` or same pattern but with the opening square bracket.

Any elegant ideas?

Comment: chrX:43612033 is acceptable ? chr10X:43612033?

Comment: yes `'chrX:43612033'` is acceptable
the other option would be `'chr10:43612033'` - so without the X after 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you could simply use `regex` by utilizing this pattern:

```
chr<digits>or<XY>:<digits>
```

[Check out this if you want to learn more about regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Here's a working example:

```py
import re

strings = [
    '[chr10:43612033[C',
    '[chr10:61665880[G',
    'C[chr20:3835205[',
    ']chr20:3870375]T',
    'G]chr6:117650611]',
    'G]chrX:117650611]',
    'G]chrY:117650611]',
]
print([re.search(r"chr(\d{1,2}?|[X-Y]):\d{,9}", s).group(0) for s in strings])
```

Output:

```
['chr10:43612033', 'chr10:61665880', 'chr20:3835205', 'chr20:3870375', 'chr6:117650611', 'chrX:117650611', 'chrY:117650611']
```

Comment: Oh wow this is an entire universe. I'd like to link some more regex references for other newbies like me: [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and this [page on stack overflow which shows many resources for python](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info/). For the last link scroll to heading "Further Reading"!